# What are characters not supported in sql char and varchar datatype

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have used name column in table. In that column i used varchar for datatype in sql. I have updated query like other languages except English but sql stored that characters as "?".
Example :

> table : student
>
> column : name (varchar(50)), id number
>
> query : `update student set name='தமிழ்' where id=10;`
>
> ans : ?????

Please say how it can avoid. And please say what are the characters sql varchar datatype store like `??`

Comment: I'd say that depends entirely on the database character set configuration.

Comment: @Nyerguds, it's partially true. It depends on data type used to store data. Please, see my answer.

Comment: No info was given about the way the DB is accessed though. Many DB access systems determine the type automatically if you actually use parameter objects. Which should always be done to avoid problems of the 'Little Bobby Tables' kind. https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to store text in your language you have to use `nchar` or `nvarchar` data type, which support UNICODE.

See: [nchar and nvarchar (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Do not forget to use proper collation.

See: [Collation and Unicode Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx)

So, a column `name (varchar(50))` should be  `name (nvarchar(50))`, then

```
UPDATE Student SET [Name] = N'NameInHindi' WHERE ID =10;
```

Comment: Thanks Los for your valid suggestion. I got it.